# Configuring SQL Reporting services 2008 Authentication Without AD/Domain

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reportmanager

Is is possible co to configure Reporting services 2008 Authentication method this way that i"ll be able to access the report manager not from build-in computer user?
My purpose is connecting to report manager (with admin rights) from another computer with a custom user and password - like connecting to Database Engine with SQL SERVER authentication method.
i have no Active directory of domain.

thank you,
Eddie

Comment: I don't think you can do this.